# Looking up a specific value from a table

Tags: filter, powerbi, max, dax, lookup

I have the below function that works, but what I'm not sure how to do is within the devices table there is a `[CreatedBy]` column. I want to pull the `[UserDeviceType]` for the most recent `[CreatedBy]` row by `[user]`

How could I modify the below to do this?

```
UserDeviceType = 
    CALCULATE(
        MAX('devices'[UserDeviceType]),
        FILTER(
            'devices',
            'devices'[user] = 'users'[_id]
        )
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For calculated column, the following formula works:

```
UserDeviceType = 
VAR _user = [_id]
VAR _tbl = FILTER(devices, [user] = _user)
VAR _latest = MAXX(_tbl, [CreatedBy])
RETURN MAXX(FILTER(_tbl, [CreatedBy] = _latest), [UserDeviceType])
```

[image]

**`devices`** table:
[image]

Comment: Please don't use images for data, use formatted text.